# finding an element recursively (c++)

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int searching(string arr [],int sizee,string element) {
    static int location;
    if(arr[sizee-1]==element) {
        location = sizee;
        return location;
    }
    else location = searching(arr, sizee-1, element);
}
```

I have used this function to search for element.

It works for array of size 2 but more than that it gives me wrong place. 
Also I want to know how to make it return -1 if it couldn't find the element.

Comment: In some languages it is encouraged to use recursion for iteration. C++ isn't currently one of them, though the situation is changing due to the popularity of so-called "functional" programming. Be aware that most C++ programmers would write this function iteratively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong/not needed with your code.  The biggest issue is you do not have a stop condition for when the element does not exist in the array.  Currently you just go negative and accessing the array with a negative index is undefined behavior.

Another issue is `location`.  It is not needed.  Once you find the element you just return the position directly.  No need to set a variable and then return that variable.  So making those changes gives you a function that looks like

```
int searching(string arr [],int sizee,string element) {
    if (sizee <= 0)
        return -1; // we did not find the element in the array or the caller gave us a negative size
    if(arr[sizee-1]==element)
        return sizee-1; // just return the index you used
    // no else needed here.  Just return the result of calling the function recursively 
    return searching(arr, sizee-1, element);
}
```

Comment: I would write `if (sizee <= 0)` to make the function valid for any value of the `sizee` argument.

Comment: @Titou To guard against the caller calling the function with a negative size?

Comment: sizee should really be a size_t. So it can't go negative. Not  a good feature of size_t in my opinion, but that's the convention.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, because 1) the argument may be computed rather than written, and 2) because writing partially defined functions is a bad habit.

Comment: @Titou this code you wrote is write but in my case i don't need it as i already checked it in the main function but thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

first, you must ensure, sizee greater than zero, or you will over flow.second, the third function parameter element's data type should be char, no string.